# Magento After Moving Media Folder over live server Product Images not showing in front and backend

Tags: linux, windows, magento, ftp

I want to know when i try to move media folder over live server from local, Images not showing in back-end and front-end of products. After searching i come out the issue that windows not allow to create case sensitive folders while in linux it will allow. So that was the issue.But for finding this solution takes 1 days of my. So i just come here to know from experts, How to deal with this kind of problem? Is there any ways so when uploading media folder over live and if it's linux server then also it works.

Means any trick or solution regarding that In magento....

Answer (score 0):

When working on Windows server make sure you use naming conventions that suit your Linux server aswell.
In short while working on windows server assume it as a Linux server while giving folder names or image names.

Comment: but in magento folder name create by default i am not creating it.. its create automatically by magento when i import product or add new product from admin side.

Answer (score 0):

Your media folder may use lower and upper case folder names which is fine on a linux system, but if you import it to a windows based system, folders like 'a' and 'A' will replace each other.

(Because Linux is case sensitive, and Windows is not)

I would simply use linux for local hosting, maybe as a virtual machine or something. You just have to prevend windows from replace half of you images.